# Where are automatic screenshots stored?

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot, snapshot

When an app goes into the background, iOS automatically takes screenshots to use in the app carousel.
I'm trying to find where automatic screenshots are stored.

I found several possible options, but nothing.

> /Library/Caches/Snapshots/$(BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)/
> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/$APP_ID/Library/Caches/Snapshots/

Answer (score 2):

I found that screenshots will be saved here:

```
/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{DEVICE_ID}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{APP_ID}/Library/SplashBoard/Snapshots/sceneID:{BUNDLE_ID}-default
```

Note: The screenshot will be saved only if you minimize the application (go to the home screen or another application).

Comment: That may be the case on the simulator, but you cannot reach those screenshots from within the app itself.

Answer (score 1):

They are not stored anywhere such that you can access them.